# Java - get the current class name?

Tags: java, class, classname

All I am trying to do is to get the current class name, and java appends a useless non-sense **$1** to the end of my class name. How can I get rid of it and only return the actual class name?

```
String className = this.getClass().getName();
```

Comment: Where are you calling this? Is it from within an anonymous inner class? Could you add some more code that shows details about the definition of the class and where this line is being called from?

Comment: So, all you want is `String className = getClass().getName().substring(0, getClass().getName().indexOf("$"))`

Comment: If you get `$1` then, because the name of the class is `$1`. If you expect something else, use `this` in the right class instead of the wrong one.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

The "$1" is not "useless non-sense". If your class is anonymous, a number is appended.

If you don't want the class itself, but its declaring class, then you can use `getEnclosingClass()`. For example:

```
Class<?> enclosingClass = getClass().getEnclosingClass();
if (enclosingClass != null) {
  System.out.println(enclosingClass.getName());
} else {
  System.out.println(getClass().getName());
}
```

You can move that in some static utility method.

But note that this is not the current class name. The anonymous class is different class than its enclosing class. The case is similar for inner classes.

Comment: But what if the enclosing class is also an anonymous inner class? Don't you have to recursively get the enclosing class until it returns `null`, and use the last non-`null` class you got?

Answer (score 340):

Try,

```
String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

This will work as long as you don't use it in a static method.

Comment: Actually, no this won't work. This question indicates he has an anonymous inner class, and for this case, getSimpleName() returns `""`

Comment: Even though this does not answer the question, this SO post is currently in the top results for "get class name java" on google, and so it is still helpful to the community.

Comment: It will return name without package namespace. Good one!

Comment: For how to get the class name in a static method [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29477085/4850949).

Answer (score 35):

Try using this
`this.getClass().getCanonicalName()` or `this.getClass().getSimpleName()`.  If it's an anonymous class, use `this.getClass().getSuperclass().getName()`

Comment: Actually, it does.  Depending.  If you are trying to get the name of the abstract class you are implementing with an anonymous class, this is what you use.

Comment: for his case (anonymous class), the simple name is empty, the canconical name is null and the superclass is Object.

Comment: Yes, yes, no.  My first two were just guesses, the third, however, is correct.  An anonymous class is a subclass of the class it implements.  That's why they work.  Thus, the superclass is the abstract class.

Comment: Weird isn't the super class the class you are inheriting from? Handler is not Inheriting form my class, it's just a member

Comment: Umm... I have tested this, and I get that the superclass of the anonymous class is the abstract class.  I will recheck my logic... but as I am getting the result that makes sense, I don't think it's me that has made the mistake....

Comment: Ahh, you're probably using "this" while I am using the actual anonymous class variable (whatever it is).  When you say "this", you are referring to the object where it is being executed, not the anonymous class itself.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `this.getClass().getSimpleName()`, like so:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {

    int x;
    int y;  

    public String getClassName() {

        String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName(); 
        System.out.println("Name:" + className);
        return className;
    }

    public Field[] getAttributes() {

        Field[] attributes = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();   
        for(int i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Declared Fields" + attributes[i]);    
        }

        return attributes;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Test t = new Test();
        t.getClassName();
        t.getAttributes();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The combination of both answers. Also prints a method name:

```
Class thisClass = new Object(){}.getClass();
String className = thisClass.getEnclosingClass().getSimpleName();
String methodName = thisClass.getEnclosingMethod().getName();
Log.d("app", className + ":" + methodName);
```

Answer (score 3):

this answer is late, but i think there is another way to do this in the context of anonymous handler class.

let's say:

```
class A {
    void foo() {
        obj.addHandler(new Handler() {
            void bar() {
                String className=A.this.getClass().getName();
                // ...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

it will achieve the same result. additionally, it's actually quite convenience since every class is defined at compile time, so no dynamicity is damaged.

above that, if the class is really nested, i.e. `A` actually is enclosed by `B`, the class of B can be easily known as:

```
B.this.getClass().getName()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Android variant, but same principle can be used in plain Java too.

```
private static final String TAG = YourClass.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String TAG = YourClass.class.getName();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `this` probably refers to an anonymous class instance. Java gives a name to those classes by appending a `$number` to the name of the enclosing class.

Comment: Non-anonymous inner classes are named Outer$Inner. This will be an anonymous class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is happening for an anonymous class. When you create an anonymous class you actually create a class that extends the class whose name you got.

The "cleaner" way to get the name you want is:

If your class is an anonymous inner class, `getSuperClass()` should give you the class that it was created from. If you created it from an interface than you're sort of SOL because the best you can do is `getInterfaces()` which might give you more than one interface.

The "hacky" way is to just get the name with `getClassName()` and use a regex to drop the `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use this Java class:

```
private String getCurrentProcessName() {
    String processName = "";
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : manager.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
        if (processInfo.pid == pid) {
            processName = processInfo.processName;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return processName;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I've found this to work for my code,, however my code is getting the class out of an array within a for loop.

```
String className="";

className = list[i].getClass().getCanonicalName();

System.out.print(className); //Use this to test it works
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything that any of the other answers haven't already said. The whole loop/array issue is irrelevant.  Also, you should look into how the code formatting works on questions/answers.

Answer (score -4):

[**Reflection APIs**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html)

> There are several Reflection APIs which return classes but these may
>   only be accessed if a Class has already been obtained either directly
>   or indirectly.
>
> ```
> Class.getSuperclass()
>      Returns the super class for the given class.
>
>         Class c = javax.swing.JButton.class.getSuperclass();
>         The super class of javax.swing.JButton is javax.swing.AbstractButton.
>
>         Class.getClasses()
> ```
>
> Returns all the public classes, interfaces, and enums that are members
>   of     the class including inherited members.
>
> ```
>         Class<?>[] c = Character.class.getClasses();
> ```
>
> Character contains two member classes Character.Subset and
>   Character.UnicodeBlock.
>
> ```
>         Class.getDeclaredClasses()
>          Returns all of the classes interfaces, and enums that are explicitly declared in this class.
>
>         Class<?>[] c = Character.class.getDeclaredClasses();
>      Character contains two public member classes Character.Subset and Character.UnicodeBlock and one private class
> ```
>
> Character.CharacterCache.
>
> ```
>         Class.getDeclaringClass()
>         java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaringClass()
>         java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaringClass()
>         java.lang.reflect.Constructor.getDeclaringClass()
>      Returns the Class in which these members were declared. Anonymous Class Declarations will not have a declaring class but will
> ```
>
> have an enclosing class.
>
> ```
>         import java.lang.reflect.Field;
>
>             Field f = System.class.getField("out");
>             Class c = f.getDeclaringClass();
>             The field out is declared in System.
>             public class MyClass {
>                 static Object o = new Object() {
>                     public void m() {} 
>                 };
>                 static Class<c> = o.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
>             }
>
>      The declaring class of the anonymous class defined by o is null.
>
>     Class.getEnclosingClass()
>      Returns the immediately enclosing class of the class.
>
>     Class c = Thread.State.class().getEnclosingClass();
>      The enclosing class of the enum Thread.State is Thread.
>
>     public class MyClass {
>         static Object o = new Object() { 
>             public void m() {} 
>         };
>         static Class<c> = o.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
>     }
>      The anonymous class defined by o is enclosed by MyClass.
> ```

Comment: Are you aware that you posted your answer as a total monolithic block of code? The statements should not be formatted as code quotes...