# Couldn't find class 'class_name_x $2', referenced from method 'class_name_x'.<init>

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-logcat

in the error text the class name is the same, the only thing changed is the end of the first class name added de '$2'

Comment: Can you edit your post to show your `class_name_x` class? We're not magical psychic fairies.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Usually a class not found is due to it not being in your build path.

Comment: This means it is trying to use an anonymous class (the second one) which is no longer there. Perhaps you forgot to deploy it.

Comment: this is the error message:
10-03 20:23:17.362: E/dalvikvm(752): Could not find class 'com.sistema.multiagente.ActividadEspera$2', referenced from method com.sistema.multiagente.ActividadEspera.<init>

Answer (score 0):

You call method of second anonymous class defined inside `class_name_x` from constructor of `class_name_x` which is shown by JVM with `.<init>` suffix.

Check out this question [Java - get the current class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271417/java-get-the-current-class-name)