# Determining the Called Class

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I have a Java program that is run in Command Line, that contains a set of classes that I have written which all contain common code elements.

Lets assume the structure is the following:

```
package.AbstractParent  (contains: static void main)
package.ClassA          (extends: AbstractParent)
package.ClassB          (extends: AbstractParent)
```

When I do the following: `java package.ClassA`, the `static void main` within the `AbstractParent` is called.

Without putting a `static void main` in `ClassA` and `ClassB`, is there a way that I can determine which was called within `AbstractParent`?

For example, when I run `java package.ClassA`, `AbstractParent` will determine `ClassA`. When I run `java package.ClassB`, `AbstractParent` will determine `ClassB`.

Comment: Do you mean this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271417/java-get-the-current-class-name)?

Comment: Not quite, as that doesn't work from Static context

Comment: >Just use TheClassName.class instead of getClass(). (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275499/how-to-call-getclass-from-a-static-method-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer fairly quick, but Googling was troublesome, so I'll leave this here.

---

In the end, I was able to use `System.getProperty("sun.java.command")` to resolve the class. However, it does contain all the subsequent arguments that are included:

```
className = System.getProperty("sun.java.command");
className = className.substring(0, className.indexOf(" "));
```

From either context, it returned either `package.ClassA` or `package.ClassB`