# how to see the class name containing the actual code

Tags: java

```
package a;
public class A {
  public String toString() {
    // return "I am an a.A"; is too primitive ;) 
    return "I am an " + getClass().getName(); // should give "a.A"
  }
}
```

--

```
package a;
public class X extends A {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    X test = new X();
    System.out.println(test);  // returns "I am an a.X"
  }
}
```

I also tried with `this.getClass()` and `super.getClass()`. How can I get the class name of where toString() and getClass() is coded actually ? (a.A)

This is just a simplified sample, my point is how to avoid hard coding the base class name in the first file (A.java)

Comment: Already answered here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6271460/6296931)

Comment: @ Coder ACJHP: Not really, or I did not find it. The question there's different anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
getClass().getName()
```

into

```
A.class.getName()
```

Comment: `this.class` wont do - "A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type followed by a `.' and the token class. It evaluates to an object of type Class, the class object for the named type (or for void). "

Answer (score 5):

```
package a;
public class A {
  public String toString() {
    return "I am an " + A.class.getName();
  }
}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

just iterate over all super

```
public String toString() {
  Class cl = getClass();
  while (cl.getSuperclass() != Object.class) 
    cl = cl.getSuperclass();
  return cl.getName();
}
```