# java: find program name, parse integer argument

Tags: java, exception, command-line-arguments, static-methods

A simple test case to demonstrate my 2 problems:

```
public class Numbers {

    private static void usage() {
        System.err.println("Usage: java " + getClass().getName() + " range");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            int range = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            usage();
        }
    }
}
```

1. Can't call `getClass()` from a static method
2. If no arguments have been supplied at the command line, I'll get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` message instead of the `usage()` output. Why doesn't **catch (Exception e)** catch it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me, exception is caught.

Getting the class name from a static method without referencing the `Numbers.class.getName()` is difficult.

But I found [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t130240-static-reference-to-current-class.html)

```
String className = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName(); 
System.err.println("Usage: java " + className + " range");
```

Answer (score 6):

1) getClass is a method on the Object type. In static methods there is no object to call the getClass on

2) The exception is caught in your example - I just tested it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this in your static method to get the class name: get the name of the class at the top of the current stack trace.

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements= new Exception().getStackTrace();
String className = stackTraceElements[0].getClassName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first question can be answered by looking at this question: [Getting the class name from a static method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936684/getting-the-class-name-from-a-static-method-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use getClass() method without an reference object.

Try this

```
System.err.println("Usage: java " + Numbers.class.getName() + " range");
```

It is not possible to use member variable/method without object reference from a static method.

```
int range = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

Above will return ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, not IOException.

So your code won't compile.

Comment: `Numbers.class.getClass()` returns Class<Class<?>> not Class<Numbers>. He should use `Numbers.class.getName()`

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is useless then. I can just hardcode the String "Numbers" in my program.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new instance of Numbers you can call `getClass()` on that.

```
(new Numbers()).getClass().getName()
```

and as @Petar Ivanov has already said, the Exception is caught as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To get the class you can do 1 of two things:

```
Class cl = null;
try
{
    cl = Class.forName("Numbers");
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
{
}
```

or:

```
Numbers n = new Numbers();
Class cl = n.getClass();
```

The first is obviously better because you don't waste memory allocating.  Though if you're just planning on returning right away, then this probably doesn't matter much in this case.