# Getting the class name from a generic static method in Java

Tags: java, oop, generics, reflection, static-methods

I have a code:

Model.java:

```
public abstract class Model <T> {
  public static <T> T find(int id) {
    T result = (T) blackMagicMethod(T.class, id);

    return result;
  }
}
```

, User.java

```
public class User extends Model<User> {
}
```

, Main.java:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(User.find(1));
  }
}
```

, blackMagicMethod:

```
public Object blackMagicMethod(Class clazz, int id) {}
```

The line `blackMagicMethod(T.class, id)` don't work, like any hacks described in [Getting the class name from a static method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936684/getting-the-class-name-from-a-static-method-in-java).

How can I make this code working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The class of a generic type is not available in runtime, i.e. `T.class` does not make sense.

The generic types gets translated to `Object` on compilation. This is what's called [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

If you really need the `class` of the type argument, you'll need to add that as an argument:

```
public abstract class Model <T> {
    public static <T> T find(Class<T> clazz, int id) {
        T result = (T) blackMagicMethod(clazz, id);
        return result;
    }
}
```