# Attempting to get class name on Android using getClassContext()[1].getName()

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, nullpointerexception

I have the following bit of code, used on Android and tested quite extensively about 6 months ago.  It has been working fine and has never been the cause of any problems.

```
private static class CurrentClassGetter extends SecurityManager {
    public String getClassName() {
      return getClassContext()[1].getName();
    }
}
```

The calling code:

```
    //---Get my name (last part of class name)
    System.out.println("Attempting to get class name");
    msSimpleName = new CurrentClassGetter().getClassName();
```

Which, I notice, is the exact same bit of code recommended by someone in this SO answer here:

[Getting the class name from a static method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936684/getting-the-class-name-from-a-static-method-in-java)

Since this code was written, I've updated my Android SDK from r14 to r16.  I also downloaded all of the newer SDK packages, from API10 (Android 2.3.3) to API15 (Android 4.0.3).  However, the above code which was working fine is now throwing this error:

```
02-22 16:18:26.779: W/System.err(2593): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 16:18:26.786: W/System.err(2593):     at com.company.myCompany.mobile.android.myCompanyApp$CurrentClassGetter.getClassName(myCompanyApp.java:413)
02-22 16:18:26.806: W/System.err(2593):     at com.company.myCompany.mobile.android.myCompanyApp.monitor(myCompanyApp.java:289)
02-22 16:18:26.806: W/System.err(2593):     at com.company.myCompany.mobile.android.myCompanyApp.monitor(myCompanyApp.java:257)
02-22 16:18:26.826: W/System.err(2593):     at com.gomez.appname.appnameActivity.onCreate(appnameActivity.java:22)
02-22 16:18:26.836: W/System.err(2593):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-22 16:18:26.846: W/System.err(2593):     at android.app.InstAppentation.callActivityOnCreate(InstAppentation.java:1049)
02-22 16:18:26.856: W/System.err(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-22 16:18:26.866: W/System.err(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-22 16:18:26.876: W/System.err(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-22 16:18:26.876: W/System.err(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-22 16:18:26.896: W/System.err(2593):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 16:18:26.896: W/System.err(2593):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 16:18:26.906: W/System.err(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-22 16:18:26.926: W/System.err(2593):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 16:18:26.926: W/System.err(2593):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 16:18:26.946: W/System.err(2593):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-22 16:18:26.946: W/System.err(2593):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-22 16:18:26.956: W/System.err(2593):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Basically, what you're looking at is a call from onCreate in Android to my private API.  Within the API, it's trying to get the current class name using the above code.

The Target API version was 8 then and it's 8 now (Android v2.2), so that has not changed at all.  Java compliance level 1.6, running Java 1.6.0_24 64-bit.

Does anyone know why getClassContext()[1].getName() would be throwing a NullPointerException like this all of a sudden, when it worked before?

Comment: Did you try to remove Android SDK v16 from your machine and install the v14 again to confirm that SDK version is the only difference?

Comment: Working on that now, on a clean machine (I need v16 for other stuff as well so I can't remove it from this system).  It takes a surprisingly long time to download all of different pieces of the SDK.

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing so far, the context from which the array of classes is derived is empty within getClassName().  I don't think it used to be like this.  Outside of the call to getClassName(), I can see a ton of stuff in "this".  Within the call, totally empty.

Comment: Confirmed. Something has changed between the Android SDK r13 and r16 that causes this call to return a null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No fix in sight, I ended up removing this block of code entirely.  It was only being used in debug output anyway and it wasn't worth the research to figure out why this was failing.