# How to get current class name including package name in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, package, classname

I'm working on a project and one requirement is if the 2nd argument for the main method starts with “`/`” (for linux) it should consider it as an absolute path (not a problem), but if it doesn't start with “`/`”, it should get the *current working path* of the class and append to it the given argument.

I can get the class name in several ways: `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`, `new File(".")` and `getCanonicalPath()`, and so on...

The problem is, this only gives me the directory in which the packages are stored - i.e. if I have a class stored in "`.../project/this/is/package/name`", it would only give me "`/project/`" and ignores the package name where the actual `.class files` lives.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Here's the explanation, taken from the exercise description

> sourcedir can be either absolute (starting with “/”) or relative to where we run the program from

sourcedir is a given argument for the main method. how can I find that path?

Comment: What will you do if the code is packaged in a JAR (or is otherwise not in a folder/file structure like you're assuming)? It's a dangerous assumption; this might work fine for a small experiment, class assignment, or other disposable situation, but PLEASE don't get into the habit of making that assumption for production-quality code.

Comment: There is no sense in finding the path to the class file. Also the exercise description does not mention that if you read it carefully (*where we run the program from* means the current path from which the program is called by the user).

Comment: Maybe you could help me to better understand the requirement? I need to check the argument starts with a '/' (mention in the description). if it does, just use it as absolute. as is. but if it doesn't, how should I treat it?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Use `this.getClass().getCanonicalName()` to get the full class name.

Note that a package / class name ("a.b.C") is different from the path of the .class files (a/b/C.class), and that using the package name / class name to derive a path is typically bad practice. Sets of class files / packages can be in multiple different class paths, which can be directories or jar files.

Comment: thanks, but it's in the main method, and 'this' can't be used in static methods. any work around it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936684/getting-the-class-name-from-a-static-method-in-java

Answer (score 34):

There is a class, [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), that can do this:

```
Class c = Class.forName("MyClass"); // if you want to specify a class
Class c = this.getClass();          // if you want to use the current class

System.out.println("Package: "+c.getPackage()+"\nClass: "+c.getSimpleName()+"\nFull Identifier: "+c.getName());
```

If `c` represented the class `MyClass` in the package `mypackage`, the above code would print:

> Package: mypackage
>   Class: MyClass
>   Full Identifier: mypackage.MyClass

You can take this information and modify it for whatever you need, or go [check the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for more information.

Comment: Note that Class.forName("MyClass") will only work if it is in the default package (i.e. has no package declaration).

Comment: @TheNail true, and `getName()` returns the package name along with the class name, editing now.

Comment: Use `getSimpleName()` to get only the class name without package name.

Comment: Instead of `Class.forName("MyClass")` you should use `MyClass.class` unless you really need runtime discovery for some other reason.

Answer (score 16):

The fully-qualified name is opbtained as follows:

```
String fqn = YourClass.class.getName();
```

But you need to read a classpath resource. So use

```
InputStream in = YourClass.getResourceAsStream("resource.txt");
```

Answer (score 8):

use `this.getClass().getName()` to get `packageName.className` and use `this.getClass().getSimpleName()` to get only class name