# How to get LOG TAG in file with @file:JvmName("")

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is there any method that allows to create LOG_TAG in similar way to

```
private val LOG_TAG = ThemeUtils::class.java.simpleName
```

but without object / class ??

I mean in file with

```
@file:JvmName("")
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you using java or kotlin?

Comment: for class name and package name have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9729288/9087754