# Java checkstyle: how to write a check which is comparing class suffix to its package

Tags: java, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

How would I write a check which checks if the class is in the right package according to its suffix, eg.: class named `DateTimeUtils` should be in a package ending in `*.util`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current class name including package name in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729197/how-to-get-current-class-name-including-package-name-in-java)

Comment: @vincrichaud Checkstyle doesn't have access to reflection

Comment: I think you can write a sub class of `AbstractFileSetCheck` for this (see https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/writingchecks.html). It has access to the file, and therefore the filename and path.