# GCM with custom broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing gcm notifications in my application. Because I use my code to generate lot of application with different package names I cannot use standard mypackage.GCMIntentService name. When generating applications I do changes only in Manifest and change imports of my R class. So I impelented my own BroadcastReceiver

```
public class GCMReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
    return GCMIntentService.class.getName();
  }
}
```

to return name of GCMIntentService regardless of package name.

Here is my manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission
        android:name="org.rferl.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="org.rferl.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <service
        android:name="org.rferl.service.GCMIntentService"
        android:enabled="true" />


   <receiver
        android:name="org.rferl.GCMReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="org.rferl" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Everything works fine, I can register, unregister, receive messages. But when application is  not runnig no GCMIntentService.onMessage is not called. Am I missing something in my manifest? Why system did not start service?

Comment: I am also stuck with same problem? Is your problem solved now? Please see my latest question from my account and guide me accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

### To change package/class name for application/`GCMIntentService`/`GCMBroadcastReceiver` for Android GCM (using Eclipse ADT)

**Note**: *You are advised to verify that you can receive messages through GCM before making the following changes. To implement GCM in Android app using the application's **default package name**, see [GCM: Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html).*

---

#### Package name

To change package name of your app (e.g., new package name = `com.example.newpackage`),

- In Package Explorer, right click the project → Android Tools → Rename Application Package.
  This updates the package name automatically and conveniently.
- In `AndroidManifest.xml`, update the package name in `permission` and `uses-permission` for `C2D_MESSAGE`:

  ```
  <permission android:name="com.example.newpackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.newpackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  ```
- In `AndroidManifest.xml`, update the package name in `category` of the `receiver`:

  ```
  <receiver
      android:name="com.example.oldpackage.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >  <!-- Not this one!! -->
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

          <category android:name="com.example.newpackage" />  <!-- This one!! -->
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  ```

---

#### Name of `GCMIntentService`

If your app's package name is `com.example.newpackage`, your `GCMIntentService` must be called `com.example.newpackage.GCMIntentService`. If not,

- Create a new class that `extends` `GCMBroadcastReceiver` and override `getGCMIntentServiceClassName()`:

  ```
  public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver
  {
      @Override
      protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context)
      {
          return MyIntentService.class.getName(); // Don't hard-code like "com.example.oldpackage.MyIntentService", see http://stackoverflow.com/a/936696/1402846
      }
  }
  ```

  *this is based on [Google's documentation on GCMBroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBroadcastReceiver.html):*

  > By default, the [`GCMBaseIntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html) class belongs to the application main package and is named [`DEFAULT_INTENT_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMConstants.html#DEFAULT_INTENT_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME). To use a new class, the [`getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBroadcastReceiver.html#getGCMIntentServiceClassName(android.content.Context)) must be overridden.
- In `AndroidManifest.xml`, update the name of the `receiver`:

  ```
  <receiver
      android:name="com.example.oldpackage.MyBroadcastReceiver"
      ... >
  </receiver>
  ```
- In `AndroidManifest.xml`, update the name of the `service`:

  ```
  <service android:name="com.example.oldpackage.MyIntentService" />
  ```

---

#### Name of `GCMBroadcastReceiver`

If your changed the package/class name of `GCMBroadcastReceiver`:

- In `AndroidManifest.xml`, update the name of the `receiver`:

  ```
  <receiver
      android:name="com.example.oldpackage.NewBroadcastReceiver"
      ... >
  </receiver>
  ```

---

#### Troubleshooting

- Verify that in `AndroidManifest.xml`, the package name should appear at least 4 times:

  - In `manifest`:

    ```
    <manifest ...
        package="com.example.newpackage" ...
    ```
  - In `permission`:

    ```
    <permission android:name="com.example.newpackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    ```
  - In `uses-permission`:

    ```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.newpackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    ```
  - In `category` within `intent-filter` within `receiver` for the GCM broadcast receiver:

    ```
    <category android:name="com.example.newpackage" />
    ```
- If you changed your package name, uninstall the old app on your device/emulator before testing.
- If you changed your package name, notice that the registration ID (that you receive in [`onRegistered()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html#onRegistered(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String))) has changed.
- If you received your registration ID in [`onRegistered()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html#onRegistered(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)), you should see something like this in LogCat (tag `GCMBroadcastReceiver`):

  ```
  GCMBroadcastReceiver        onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
  GCMBroadcastReceiver        GCM IntentService class: com.example.oldpackage.MyIntentService
  ```

  Verify that the package/class name of the intent service is correct.
- If you override [`getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBroadcastReceiver.html#getGCMIntentServiceClassName(android.content.Context)) in your own `GCMBroadcastReceiver`, you should see something like this in LogCat (tag `GCMRegistrar`):

  ```
  GCMRegistrar        Setting the name of retry receiver class to com.example.oldpackage.MyBroadcastReceiver
  ```

  Verify that the package/class name of the broadcast receiver is correct.
- When your server sends a message to GCM server, check the HTTP status code and HTTP response for errors.
- And if you are desperate:

  - Check LogCat for errors.
  - Try restarting your device/emulator.
  - Try uninstalling your app on the device/emulator.
  - Try restarting Eclipse.
  - Try clean and re-build the project.
  - Try updating ADT (Pull down menu → Window → Android SDK Manager → Install packages).
  - Try updating Eclipse (Pull down menu → Help → Check for Updates).
  - Try restarting your computer.
  - Get a good sleep, or pray.

Answer (score 2):

You should put GCMIntentService class into your root application package.
Here org.rferl

```
<service
    android:name=".GCMIntentService"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

and receiver

```
   <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.EgoSecure.ma" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: It is not possible due to using source code as base to generate many applications - they have to have different package name which I change in manifest. So if I generate application for example org.rferl.en then I need to change package structure for many classes change imports and so...
Also I wrote that everything works fine when application is running I can receive messages. Only system does not call receiver or start service when application is not running.

Comment: If you use Android 3.0 or > ,you must set flag for "stopped" applications

Comment: you are right, stopped application is also killed by user. So I killed it during testing. I am not able to test it right know because server guys are from other company. Also sample from google does not work when I killed it manually. But when I started it and for example turn off phone everything works.   
But how to put this flag in manifest file? I usually kills aplications on my phone if something went wrong and untill I start them I am not able receive messages. Little strange behaviour.

Comment: Flag should add to your broadcast intent -"include stopped packages".But if you not receive gcm data from the server that does not help you.

Comment: It is not my intent. This Intent which calls my receiver provides GCM service. So I have no control to update, create it programaticaly.

Comment: Change your broadcast receiver as i describe above

Answer (score 2):

> Because I use my code to generate lot of application with different package names I cannot use standard mypackage.GCMIntentService name.

I'm not sure whether you ask for a runtime or a build time solution. The other answers are runtime solutions so I thought I add some information on possibilites during build time.

---

In AndroidManifest, you can use the variable `$PACKAGE_NAME` (available by default) which will refer to the package name you specified in the attribute `package` in the `manifest` root element.

The value of this `package` attribute needs not be a hard coded string but can also be set dynamically via resource reference like so:

```
<manifest package="@string/app_package" ...>
    ...
    <service
        android:name="$PACKAGE_NAME.service.GCMIntentService"
        android:enabled="true" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Note `.service` is just a subpackage that I included to show how you specify these. Of course, this solution would work only if your applications follow general rules like putting Service classes in a `.service` subpackage.

Also note, that you can actually leave the root package off completely. It will be expanded by Android:

```
<manifest package="@string/app_package" ...>
    ...
    <service
        android:name=".service.GCMIntentService"
        android:enabled="true" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

In effect, same as above.

If you are looking for a more flexible way to replace values in an AndroidManifest (or different files), you might want to have a look at the Ant Replace task (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) or Resource Filtering (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

The gcm broadcast receiver (GCMBroadcastReceiver.class) calls intent service class (GCMIntentService.class) from application root directory. You cannot use "org.rferl.service.GCMIntentService" right now. You should override getGCMIntentServiceClassName method from GCMBroadcastReceiver, that returns name of your GCMIntentService class. How to do that, [here](http://dexxtr.com/post/28188228252/rename-or-change-package-of-gcmintentservice-class)