# Something like `this.class` instead of `ClassName.class`?

Tags: java, android

When I define Android service classes, I often define (in fact, copy&paste) static methods that start the service with given data:

```
public class MyShinyBackgroundService extends Service 
{
    ...
    // start this service if it's not running; pass data
    public static void startServiceWithData(String data, Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBackgroundService.class);
        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(DATA_KEY, data);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Probably you already see the bug: this method invokes a wrong service. (A stupid copy&paste bug. It would not happen if I could write something like `this.class`, but unfortunately it is not syntactically valid.)

Is there a way in Java to reference the `.class` of *"this class"* from a static method other than by class name?

**EDIT**

I disagree with @CommonsWare about this question being duplicate because I need the `.class` rather than class name; nevertheless, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936724/755804) indeed suggested a good enough hack that makes the code copy/paste-safe:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingClass());
```

(the braces in `new Object(){}` are important!!!)

***I definitely would prefer a less hackish solution, so I ask the readers to vote for reopening this question.***

**EDIT 2**

Now I'm inclined to define `thisClass` as a **private** static class member (private because it would be wrong to let this class member be inherited or referenced from elsewhere since `MyShinyBackgroundService.thisClass` is the same as `MyShinyBackgroundService.class`). It is really stupid that `class` is a reserved word in Java so that the field `class` must be referenced via an alias.

```
private static Class thisClass = MyShinyBackgroundService.class;
...   
public static void startServiceFrom(Context someContext) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(someContext, thisClass);
    someContext.startService(intent);
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use this.class?

Comment: @holtc Because the method is `static`?

Comment: Moral of the story: don't recklessly copy&paste code around

Comment: You could try and pass in the class when executing the static service

    public static void startServiceWithData(String data, Context context, Class<?> cls) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, cls);
        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(DATA_KEY, data);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

Comment: I am not sure if I agree with the dupe @CommonsWare.

Comment: Probably abusing the stacktrace or with the creation of an anonymous class one might receive the class name as String, and then do a `Class.forName`. And being called pervert.