# Is there a generic way to get the name of a Java class in a static context?

Tags: java, slf4j

I use the following code snippet to create an slf4j Logger object

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

and copy it to a new class when I'm working on it, but from time to time I'll forget to change the class name, and create a Logger object for MyClass in a class called YourClass, which leads to confusing statements in the logs.

I know the recommendation for getting the name of a class is to use MyClass.class.getName(), but is there a generic snippet I can use to instantiate a Logger that can be copied to new classes without needing any changes?

Comment: A better idea would be to edit the new class template on your IDE to include a logger with the proper classname.

Comment: Don't do this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/936724/6253321

Comment: No. Not in a static context. You could potentially setup a generator in your IDE for it though. For example, in Eclipse, you might do a custom template and something like `private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(${enclosing_type});`

Comment: You can use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)'s logging annotations like `@Slf4j` to automatically generate the logging field for you based on the class name.

Comment: Lombok's annotations would be my choice too, if you really find your copy-paste method to be that error prone.

Comment: Thanks, I like the template solution for its simplicity, and I hadn't heard of Lombok's annotations, so I'll check that out.

@Michael it's not a massive problem, I'd estimate it happens in abuot one in every 50 classes I work on, but that's still enough to make me look for a solution